# Using proper names

Tags: html

My HTML tag specifies `lang="en"`, but there are a lot of proper names in the document. These are such things as surnames, which the validator flags as spelling mistakes. I'd like to put them in a `<span>` with `lang="none"` for example. Is there a correct way of doing this (i.e. one which validates as correct HTML?

Comment: The solution is to ignore the validator. Spelling errors don't invalidate HTML. The document *is* valid, spell checking is something that the validator provides as an extra feature.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Juhana, but when the validator throws up hundreds of such errors, it's hard to find the REAL problems.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it is to set the attribute to an empty string

```
<span lang="">...</span>
```

> To determine the language of a node, user agents must look at the nearest ancestor element (including the element itself if the node is an element) that has a lang attribute in the XML namespace set or is an HTML element and has a lang in no namespace attribute set. That attribute specifies the language of the node (regardless of its value).
>
> If the resulting value is the empty string, then it must be interpreted as meaning that the language of the node is explicitly unknown.

[HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml%3Alang-attributes)

Comment: Thanks, Dave. That looks good but Total Validator still complains.

Comment: I don't know what you want - I showed you the correct way to do it, according to the spec.  If your validator doesn't like it, that's a problem with the validator, not with your code.  Have you tried using any other validators?

Comment: I have reported the bug to Total Validator. Nu Html Checker seems OK in this respect.

Comment: Total Validator Support replied: Unfortunately, our spell checker isn't that intelligent. You can only specify one language, and using the 'lang' attribute has no effect. We have our own ignore mechanism, but we realise that it isn't a great solution here, and the 'lang' attribute is the correct way of marking html.